# uGet Proxy Authentication

Tags: proxy, authentication, uget

I am trying to download a file from which my computer is behind a proxy server but when I enter my username and password in uGet i still get the `407 Proxy Authentication Required` error.

Any solutions?

Comment: uGet Proxy is for connecting to a proxy server not inside your own proxy server that you are already utilizing. If you are already using a proxy uGet will just use whatever the default that network manager is using.

Comment: @MichaelTunnell So there is now way to download files from the internet with uGet if my network is behind a proxy?

Comment: It depends because it is possible that your proxy is blocking other proxies from being used inside of itself based on the protocols for example.